# How to perform full postback from a button in RadWindow

Tags: asp.net, telerik

We show a RadWindow from within a RadAjaxPanel.  We would like to have a button inside the RadWindow which does some work, closes the RadWindow and finally, has to do a full (parent) page post back.

Is it possible at all?  When we tried to accomplish this, the button was doing async postback and does not even close RadWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are details on using a RadWindow with AJAX: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radwindow-ajaxifying.html. If your button is not inside such update panels/RadAjaxPanels/AjaxSettings it will perform a full postback which will close the RadWindow in the process (see [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/opening-radwindow-from-the-server.aspx) on opening it from the server without having it re-show).

Now, if you are loading an entire page in your RadWindow this button should call a JavaScript function on that page, and this function will access the main page and will initiate the postback. See how to create these functions here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-calling-functions.html. A postback can be initiated in many ways, e.g. the __doPostBack() function, $get('myButtonClientID').click(), etc.